# Handling magic constants during 64-bit migration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, 32bit-64bit

I confess I did something dumb and it now bites me. I used a magic number constant defined as `NSUIntegerMax` to define a special case index. The value is normally used as index to access selected item in `NSArray`. In the special case, denoted by the magic number I get the value from elsewhere, instead of from the array.

This index value is serialized in User Defaults as `NSNumber`.

With Xcode 5.1 my iOS app gets compiled with standard architecture that now also includes arm64. This changed the value of `NSUIntegerMax`, so now after deserialization I get 32-bit value of `NSUIntegerMax`, which no longer matches in comparisons with the magic number, whose value is now 64-bit `NSUIntegerMax`. And it results in `NSRangeException` with reason: `-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]`.

It is a minor issue in my code, given the normal range of that array is small, I may just get away with redefining my magic number as `4294967295`. But it doesn't feel right. How should I have handled this issue properly? 
I guess avoiding the magic number altogether would be the most robust approach?

#### Note

I think the problem with my magic number is roughly equivalent to what happened to `NSNotFound` constant. Apple's [64-bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/) says in section about [Common Type-Conversion Problems in Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW16):

> - Working with constants defined in the framework as `NSInteger`. Of particular note is the `NSNotFound` constant. In the 64-bit runtime, its value is larger than the maximum range of an int type, so truncating its value often causes errors in your app.

… but it does not say what should be done, except to be careful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSInteger/NSUInteger it's 4b on 32bit OS and 8b on 64 OS.

If you want to use the the same size integer for both OSs you should consider use `int (4)` or `long long (8)` or int32_t/int64_t. To get max int from int you can use cast:

```
(int)INT_MAX
//or LONG_MAX
```